# Compare strings - whitespace issue

Tags: plsql

I need to compare two strings which are identical but one comes in with `%20` replacing whitespace:

```
test1 = 'My Test'
test2 = 'My%20Test'
```

So when my program retrieves test2 from database and tries to compare it to test1, it comes out as not equal. How can I replace whitespace in test1 with `%20`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some of the strings are url escaped. If you unescape both strings they should be equal. There is no need to replace the whitespaces with %20, just unescape will get rid of the url encoded characters.

```
koen19c>select 
  2    utl_url.unescape('My Test'), 
  3    utl_url.unescape('My%20Test') 
  4*  from dual;

UTL_URL.UNESCAPE('MYTEST')    UTL_URL.UNESCAPE('MY%20TEST')    
_____________________________ ________________________________ 
My Test                       My Test                          

koen19c>
```

and they're the same:

```
koen19c>select 
  2    CASE WHEN utl_url.unescape('My Test') = utl_url.unescape('My%20Test') 
  3      THEN 'Same'
  4      ELSE 'Not Same'
  5    END as "Same ?"
  6*  from dual;

Same ?    
_________ 
Same      

koen19c>
```

If you want to replace all whitespaces with the escaped value, then the safest bet is to first unescape, then escape to prevent a double escape:

```
koen19c>set serveroutput on 
koen19c>DECLARE
  2    l_string1 VARCHAR2(10) := 'My Test';
  3    l_string2 VARCHAR2(10) := 'My%20Test';
  4  BEGIN
  5    dbms_output.put_line('-- just escape, string2 is double escaped now');
  6    dbms_output.put_line(utl_url.escape(l_string1));
  7    dbms_output.put_line(utl_url.escape(l_string2));
  8    dbms_output.put_line('-- unescape then escape');
  9    dbms_output.put_line(utl_url.escape(utl_url.unescape(l_string1)));
 10    dbms_output.put_line(utl_url.escape(utl_url.unescape(l_string2)));
 11    
 12  END;
 13* /
-- just escape, string2 is double escaped now
My%20Test
My%2520Test
-- unescape then escape
My%20Test
My%20Test


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

koen19c>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, *literally* replace?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'My test'        from dual union all
  3     select 'My second test' from dual
  4    )
  5  select col, replace(col, ' ', '%20') new_col
  6  from test;

COL            NEW_COL
-------------- ------------------------------------------
My test        My%20test
My second test My%20second%20test

SQL>
```

---

Comparing:

```
SQL> with test (col, col2) as
  2    (select 'My test'       , 'My%20test'           from dual union all
  3     select 'My second test', 'My%20second%20test' from dual union all
  4     select 'No match'      , 'No%20%match here'    from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  where col = replace(col2, '%20', ' ');

COL            COL2
-------------- ------------------
My test        My%20test
My second test My%20second%20test

SQL>
```

Comment: I don't want to just literally replace white space with hardcoded `%20` but I want to be able to compare two strings

Comment: See edited answer; is that closer to what you're looking for?